# Using pretrained convolutional network as a GAN discriminator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I've pulled some code from TF2.0 documentation to generate images from a custom dataset. The code is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/dcgan)

Since the documentation uses Keras i figured i might change the discriminator network to a pretrained network e.g InceptionV3, and only train the top layers. I've found [this](https://keras.io/applications/) code (Fine-tune InceptionV3 on a new set of classes). I cant seem to figure out how to replace the the one with the other. I understand that im trying to replace Sequential mode with the Functional API. But i guess they are somehow interconnected. However, im not a frequent Keras user.

My questions is: How do i replace a custom CNN in Sequential mode with a pretrained one from the Functional API to use as a discriminator?

EDIT: I would be happy if anyone has examples of doing it with the GANEstimator instead as im more used to TF.

**Use the generator to generate a random image**

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 3)

    return model

generator = make_generator_model()
noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)
```

**The current discriminator and helpers (Outputs tf.Tensor([[-0.0003378]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32))**

```
def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                     input_shape=[28, 28, 1]))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))

    return model

cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
decision = discriminator(generated_image)
print (decision)
```

**The desired discriminator**

```
def make_discriminator_model():
    # create the base pre-trained model
    model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

    # ADD TOP LAYERS

    # FREEZE ALL LAYERS EXCEPT TOP LAYERS

    return model

# COMPILE

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = ??? # Real Loss
    fake_loss = ??? # Fake loss
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
decision = discriminator(generated_image)
print (decision)
```

**All imports**

```
  from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

try:
  # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass
import tensorflow as tf
print('TF version: {}'.format(tf.__version__))

import glob
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time

from IPython import display
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg16
import os.path
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
```

**EDIT:
This was the discriminator i ended up with! Thanks to @pandrey**

```
def make_discriminator_model():
    pre_trained = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=IMG_SHAPE
    )
    pre_trained.trainable = False  # mark all weights as non-trainable
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([pre_trained])
    model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))   
    return model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve the building of a partly-pretrained-and-frozen model:

```py
# Load the pre-trained model and freeze it.
pre_trained = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
    weights='imagenet', include_top=False
)
pre_trained.trainable = False  # mark all weights as non-trainable
# Define a Sequential model, adding trainable layers on top of the previous.
model = tf.keras.Sequential([pre_trained])
# ADD TOP LAYERS HERE, just as you would in your example code
# You can check that the proper parameters are frozen or learnable with:
model.summary()
```

I do not think you need to alter the loss function compared to the one you gave as an example.

Comment: Thanks. It is a beautiful solution! I've edited the question with the final solution that worked for me! Big thumbs up